# How to generate a .elf file with keil v5.30 to simulate in proteus

Tags: stm32, elf, keil, proteus

how are you?. I'm looking for how to generate a .elf file with keil v5.30 to simulate in Proteus and being able to se the source code while the simulation is running but I can't find nothing, I'm simulating a stm32f103c6 and I think the compiler is ARMCC but not shure.

If not possible then is possible to generate the .elf file with another tool from keil or with the ouput files of keil?.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: for me it has, that why I'm asking, otherwise I wouldn't be asking. Please people, If you don't have any constructive to say then don't say anything. To say something not helpful is not giving you adittionall points or reputation.

Comment: then do not post on the public forum.

Comment: In adittion, If simulate doesn't have any sense then why so many people in the world tooks the effort to do simulators of electronics, civil construction, rockets, sattellites, etc. Then ask yourself why several big enterprise spends lots of money buying simulators (specially airways companies).I forgot, Spacial agencies train their crews in "simulators", why they do that if it "does not make sense"...I don't know, may be they are all mistaken -I'm being sarcastic if you didn't noted-.